# Why cant I use hardware keyboard when using VNC

Tags: remote, vnc, screen, desktop

I have a small problem. I have a spare smartphone and decided to use it as a screen for my raspberry pi 3B+. I ordered a physical keyboard and mouse for my raspi. But when I connect with my old Smartphone to the raspi through the VNC Viewer app, I cant anymore control the raspi with the keyboard connected to it.

I already tried turning on viewing mode only. But it seems that it only receives touch input from the vnc viewer app.

Comment: Works for the rest of us. You need to explain what you are trying.

Comment: Ok ill update the post

Comment: Nvm i thought i can update it. Umm so here goes

Comment: I was searching for tutorials on how to use an android phone as a screen for my pi. After i set everything up, I already accessed the desktop. The keyboard inside vnc works also the touchscreen. But I have bought a keyboard for the pi when I ordered it. And when I plugged it in after accessig the pi through vnc, it doesnt work even if i switcheed on viewing mode in the vnc viewer app